# How can I solve the problem, I cant open Preferences of android studio in my macbook

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Whenever I click the Preferences of my Android studio, nothing happens. I updated Kotlin 1.4.10 and my Android Studio tells me "Kotlin not configure". I make it from Tools>Kotlin>Configure but it does not solve. So I have to make it from Preferences but I can't open Preferences after my Kotlin update.

Comment: it's happening for me as well. were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Please reset AS settings from. that solve my problem. 

File -> IDE Settings - Reset to defaults